# How to give range in positive look behind in regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?i)(?<=\b[a-z]{4})\d+', 'abcd1234  EFGHI4567')
```

My Out

```
['1234']
```

I need to give range of {4,5} if i am giving `re.findall(r'(?i)(?<=\b[a-z]{4,5})\d+', 'abcd1234  EFGHI4567')` so that out will be `['1234','4567']` I am getting error of look behind error.

How to overcome the situation

Comment: You could use `(?i)(?<=\b[a-z]{4,5})\d+`if you use the pypi regex module https://pypi.org/project/regex/ See https://rextester.com/NGCBZJ2593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Python supports variable width lookbehinds (to my knowledge, only C# does support it).  I would rephrase your regex search without lookbehinds as:

```
inp = "abcd1234 bla123 EFGHI4567"
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]{4,5}(\d+)\b', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['1234', '4567']
```

Comment: Is there any  way to give `range in positive look behind in regex`

Comment: No, there isn't, not in Python.  You _might_ be able to use an alternation, e.g. something like `((?<=\b[a-z]{4})|(?<=\b[a-z]{5}))`, but this is ugly and also probably not very performant.  Most of the time, if you find yourself having to use a variable width lookbehind, it is time to sit down and rethink your strategy.